# Contatenating two string

Tags: vb.net, string, concatenation

i want to merge two strings

**example:**

first string : *www.org.a.org*

second string: *.org.lb*

result string : *www.org.a.org.lb*

**example:**

first string : *www.google.com*

second string: *google.com*

result string : *www.google.com*

```
dim s1 as String = "www.org.a.org"
dim s2 as String = ".org.lb"
dim s2 as String = s1 & s2 ' www.org.a.org.org.lb !!
```

Comment: This is dangerous territory. Domain extensions (TLDs) can be very complex and the list of existing TLDs is always changing. To do this correctly, you'd have to future-proof any parsing you do by downloading a current list of public TLDs every time you parse one. If, however, you're not worried about that, you could simply find the last occurrence of the period character in the original string, then drop everything from there after, then append your new extension.

Answer (score 0):

Going strictly off of the examples you provided, I would make a `Function` that would merge the strings together.

The `Function` should check if string1 contains string2 to know if any merging is necessary.  If this check is false, break string2 apart and check each piece if it is in string1 and if it's not, add it to the end (Assuming you're always adding to the end when merging).

```
Imports System

Public Module Module1

    Public Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine(MergeString("www.org.a.org", ".org.lb"))
        Console.WriteLine(MergeString("www.google.com", "google.com"))
    End Sub

    Public Function MergeString(ByVal str1 As String, ByVal str2 As String) As String
        If str1.EndsWith(str2)
            Return str1
        Else
            Dim str2Pieces() = str2.Split("."c)
            For i = 0 to str2Pieces.Length - 1
                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(str2Pieces(i)) = False
                    If str1.EndsWith(str2Pieces(i)) = False
                        str1 = str1 & "." & str2Pieces(i)
                    End If
                End If
            Next

            Return str1
        End If
    End Function
End Module
```

Output:

> www.org.a.org.lb
>
> www.google.com

Comment: In your second test, switch the 2 parameters. The output becomes `google.com.www.google.com`. I'm not sure this is what he wants.

Comment: @Guerudo The examples the OP posts indicates the first string is the beginning and the second is the add on. Otherwise, how are you supposed to know which string is the beginning, ignoring that these strings are URLs?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your question, it seems that you may have some rules that you didn't state. The following function does literally what you asked, and it returns the strings you expected in the two examples you gave.

```
Function MergeStrings(str1 As String, str2 As String) As String
    Dim pos, overlap As Integer
    If str1.Length > str2.Length Then pos = str1.Length - str2.Length 

    overlap = str1.Length - pos
    Do While overlap > 0
        If str1.Substring(pos, overlap) = str2.Substring(0, overlap) Then Return str1.Substring(0, pos) & str2 
        pos += 1
        overlap = str1.Length - pos
    Loop
    Return str1 & str2 
End Function
```